# Why getArgument() when using "doAnswer" in mockito 2 doesn't cast implicitly?

Tags: generics, java-8, casting, mockito

So now I am migrating from Mockito 1.* to 2.* and I don't understand why there is a casting problem when using getArgument() in the doAnswer. I mean when I try to invoke getArgument() in the other method argument or i try to chain methods on the retrieved object.
Here is code which worked with mockito 1.*

```
 doAnswer(invocation -> {
            try (InputStream inputStream = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, SomeResource.class).getResource().getInputStream()) {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, invocation.getArgumentAt(1, OutputStream.class));
            }
        return null;
        }).when(mockedService).downloadFile(any(), any());
```

Changing getArgumentAt() to getArgument() after migration to 2.* failed, because "getResource()" method can't be found with a type. Also getting second argument from invocation didn't work because of incompatible type.

```
doAnswer(invocation -> {
            try (InputStream inputStream = invocation.getArgument(0).getResource().getInputStream()) {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, invocation.getArgument(1));
            }
        return null;
        }).when(mockedService).downloadFile(any(), any());
```

I had to change to explicit casting in second argument or explicitly save to new reference and the same for first.
That code works:

```
doAnswer(invocation -> {
    final SomeResource input = invocation.getArgument(0);
    final OutputStream outputStream = invocation.getArgument(1);
    try (InputStream inputStream = input.getResource().getInputStream()) {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
    return null;
}).when(mockedService).downloadFile(any(), any());
```

I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Method `getArgument` is a generic method. It has following signature:

```
<T> T getArgument(int index)
```

See the [javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html).

This hadn't been possible until Java 8, which added [Generalized Target-Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101) and usually the return type class was used as one of the parameters (like in your example using Mockito 1.*).

So when you assign the result to a variable of concrete type the cast is not needed because it can be inferred. When you pass is to `IOUtils.copy()` it  can't infer a single concrete type, because the `copy` method is overloaded. If you passed it to a method, which isn't overloaded it would work without explicit cast.